# How to search for different models at the same time in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I'm looking for the easiest way to search in different models at the same time. I have 3 models: Game, Movie and Book and I want to be able to search for game, movie or book title in one query. Does anyone know an easy solution? Is this an easy task without use of plugins?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just query one Model, then the next, then the next.

If the models aren't related to each other, there's no way to return results from all of them in a single query - that's a limitation of SQL, not CakePHP (EDIT - wrong! you can using the [UNION operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)). And there's certainly no way to make a call to three models in one line or anything.

So, just make three separate queries, then do whatever you want with the results. You could display them separately, or merge them all into one array and re-sort them, then display them together - whatever tickles you.

EDIT (after my answer had already been accepted as correct!):

As @xgalvin mentioned, you can join multiple tables in 1 statement using the [UNION operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp). So, I was wrong. But unless the different tables are very similar, then the UNION operator probably isn't a good fit and you're still better off making 3 queries. If all you want is id, name and type, then @xgalvin's answer is better than mine.

Comment: Thanks for the update! "UNION" has fairly limited use but it should be slightly faster than making three queries and merging them with PHP, assuming the schema of the three tables is similar.

Answer (score 2):

Without relationship between them, in one `find()` statement? No.

You can make something like this:

```
$models = array('Game', 'Movie', 'Book');
$search = 'some title';
$results = array();

foreach($models as $model) {
    $this->loadModel($model);
    $results[$model] = $this->{$model}->find('all', array('conditions' => array($model . '.title' => $search)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Include the following in any model (lets say it's Media for this example):

```php
public function search($query) {
    $query = Sanitize::clean($query);
    $result = $this->query("
        (SELECT id, name, 'book' AS type FROM books WHERE name LIKE '%$query%')
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT id, name, 'movie' AS type FROM movies WHERE name LIKE '%$query%')
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT id, name, 'game' AS type FROM games WHERE name LIKE '%$query%')
    ");
    $result = Hash::extract($result, "{n}.{n}");
    return $result;
}
```

The `'book' AS type` part can be removed if you have some other way of identifying the element type.

Make sure you add `App::uses('Sanitize', 'Utility');` in your model file, before the class.

In the Media controller you can use:

```
$result = $this->Media->search($query);
```

Which returns something like if the query is "ca":

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => '12',
        'name' => 'Carly',
        'type' => 'book'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => '19',
        'name' => 'Camden',
        'type' => 'book'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'id' => '20',
        'name' => 'Carter',
        'type' => 'movie'
    )
);
```

Comment: If I had Media model, then I could do this and I've already thought of doing this, but they have too little in common, hence merging them will make a super huge table (they are already huge separately).

Comment: That search method will work exactly the same way if you put it in the book, movies or game model.